# GitHub masking pre-signed S3 url

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, github-actions

I have a YAML that generates a pre-signed URL.

[image]

The idea is that once the files are uploaded to S3, GitHub action UI displays a hyperlink of the S3 object and upon click, user is shown the file.

[image]

The problem is that GitHub masks the AMZ-Credential and Token and because of this, I am unable to click and go to the link.

[image]

[image]

How can I get around this?

Everything works fine if I make the bucket public and use a normal link to the file but I am concerned about the security threats.

Comment: You could also consider attaching the file as a workflow artifact. https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact

Comment: @jessehouwing Attaching the file as artifact would make the user download and extract a zip file. I am doing all this to get rid of that step and give the user a clickable link directly on the workflow page.

Comment: I wonder whether this would solve your problem: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-test-results it attaches the test result as a step summary.

Comment: That action is excellent!